# Could Somone Explain this Code What actually happening here

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

Could Someone explain what really happening in the below mentioned array. I have no idea what really the statement inside the for-loop does.Could someone Explain

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

    int main(){
        
        int m=3,n=2;
        
        int *arr[m];

        for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
            arr[i]=new int[n];
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: try examples in https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

Comment: `int m=3; int *arr[m];` is not standard C++ as `m` is not a compile-time constant. Some compilers will allow this as an extension, but it is not portable and should not be relied on. Make `m` be `const`, or else use `std::vector`. See [Why aren't variable-length arrays part of the C++ standard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097)

Comment: *Could Someone explain what really happening in the below mentioned array*  -- What really happens is a compiler error.  That array is not valid C++.

Answer (score 2):

*arr* is an array of pointers to *int*. So in the for-loop, you're creating an array of n *int* whose the first element is pointed by *arr[i]*.